# Does this time complexity for sorting match any known algorithm?

Tags: algorithm, sorting

Have been tinkering with sorting algorithms for a while and think I have a new one - a <s>n</s> <s>un</s> stable in-place algorithm whose best and worst case comparison is same at `3^(k-1) + 2^(k-1)` where `n = 2^(k)`.

I thought I had two others  - `n log(n) log(n)` and `n*k` but believe they are [inplace-merge-sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2571049/how-to-sort-in-place-using-the-merge-sort-algorithm/2571094#2571094) and [binary-quick-sort/binary-radix-sort](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2913933/binary-quicksort) respectively. However I've not so far encountered any with the above time complexity.

> Update #2 :

Question is whether there is already any known stable, in-place sorting algorithm with a time complexity of `3^(k-1) + 2^(k-1)` where `n = 2^(k)`.

Comment: I might have not get it 100%, what is the question?

Comment: Question is whether there is already any known stable, in-place sorting algorithm with a time complexity of `3^(k-1) + 2^(k-1)` where `n = 2^(k)`.

Comment: 3^(k-1) ~ 3^k ~ 3^logn = n^log3 ~ n^1.584. Nah it's too slow.

Comment: Agreed. But given that its still better than n^2 so wanted to check any how.